# Winsock Sends Empty Data

Tags: php, c++, winsock

I am trying to simulate a Winsock Request , it doesn't Send the data as it just sends empty data , the file (text File) Creates but unfortunately I don't seem to see any data in the text File.

the C++ looks like this :

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Winsock.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32")

int main()
{
    char fname[32];
    printf("Enter Your name: \n");
    scanf("%31s",fname);

    char lname[32];
    printf("Enter Your name: \n");
    scanf("%31s",lname);

    char telnum[32];
    printf("Enter Your name: \n");
    scanf("%31s",telnum);

    char email[32];
    printf("Enter Your name: \n");
    scanf("%31s",email);

    //Initiate Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);

    SOCKET m_socket;
      if(m_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP) ==INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("Invalid Socket :WSAGetLastError()");
        }
        sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    clientService.sin_port = htons(80);
    LPHOSTENT host = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");

    if(connect(m_socket,(SOCKADDR*)&clientService,sizeof(clientService))==SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
        printf("Connection Failure");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
        }

    char buffer[1024];

    strcpy(buffer,"POST /dbarea.php HTTP/1.1\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Content - Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Host: localost\n");
    strcat(buffer,"content-Length:32\n");
    strcat(buffer,"\n");
    strcat(buffer,"fname=%s&lname=%s&telnum=%s&email=%s");
    wsprintfA(buffer,fname, lname, telnum, email);
    if(!send(s, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0))
    {
        printf("Not Sent ! Error : %d", GetLastError());
    }
    else{
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Message Sent", "", MB_OK);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the php looks like this

```
<?php
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $lname = $_POST['lname'];
  $telnum = $_POST['telnum'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $log = "Data : \n First Name: $fname\n Last Name: $lname\n Telephone :  $telnum\n Email : $email";
  $file =  fopen("datas.txt","w");
  fwrite($file, $log);
  fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code, to step though it line by line to see it all works as it should, and that all variables have the values you expect them to?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, yes i have Sir and it just doesnt send it

Comment: Why do you think Winsock is sending the empty data? Lots of the data in your `$log` variable is hard coded so if you're getting a completely empty file there is a problem with your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines lead to *undefined behavior*:

```
char* fname, lname, telnum,email;
printf("Enter Your name: \n");
scanf("%s",&fname);
printf("Enter Your Last Name: \n");
scanf("%s",&lname);
printf("Enter Your Telephone: \n");
scanf("%s",&telnum);
printf("Enter Your EMail: \n");
scanf("%s",&email);
```

First you don't initialize the pointer variables, so their values will be *indeterminate* and using them in any way other than initializing them is *undefined behavior*.

The second problem is with your `scanf` calls. It's true that `scanf` expects a pointer, but those variables *are* already pointers, so using the address-of operator will give you a pointer *to the pointer*, which in this case is of type `char **`.

The solution is to use *arrays*, like e.g.

```
char fname[32];
printf("Enter Your name: \n");
scanf("%31s",fname);
```

Comment: I edited now it shows the error at Send Area to send the Data the send looks like this if(!send(s, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0))

Didnt i call the Convention correctly?